# Linked terms and conditions

Tags: cognito-forms

I need a terms and conditions page linked in the form along side a checkbox to know that people have agreed.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

Although we do not currently support this feature it is something that we are looking into for future releases. We do have a work around for this, using a Content field to link users to the specific terms and conditions. You can then add the Yes/No choice under the Content field asking if they have read and accepted the terms and conditions.